# Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I was trying to add pagination to a table which is dynamically added to HTML. When i was trying to run the code table is getting fetched but in the console I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

I have added some third party pagination methods. The following is my code:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/SignalR/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/TarAndMonUI/JavaScript_DateTime/DateTimeJavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/TarAndMonUI/Date_Time_Picker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/controls_validation.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Pagination_1.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tbl').DataTable({
      "order": [
        [10, "dsc"]
      ],
      "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
      'bSort': false,
      'aoColumns': [{
          sWidth: "45%",
          bSearchable: false,
          bSortable: false
        },
        {
          sWidth: "45%",
          bSearchable: false,
          bSortable: false
        },
        {
          sWidth: "10%",
          bSearchable: false,
          bSortable: false
        }
      ],
      "scrollY": "200px",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "info": true,
      "paging": true
    });

  });

  $(function() {
    $.connection.myHubMvc.client.displayStatusFromServer = function() {
      getData();
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
      getData();
    });

  });
  setInterval(function() {
    getData();
  }, 1000);

  function instantiateMyDatePicker() {
    $('#myDatePicker_2, #myDatePicker_1,#myDatePicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'
    });
  }

  function getData() {
    //var $tbl = $('#tbl');
    var $tbl = $('#tbl');
    var crit = $('#ddlTypes').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:58209/api/GetData',
      //data: JSON.stringify({ cri: crit }),
      data: {
        'cri': crit
      },
      //type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var tbl = '<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
        tbl += '<tr><th>Type</th><th>Journey Number</th><th>Declaration Number</th><th>Risk Level</th><th>CCPID</th><tr>';
        $tbl.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          tbl += '<tr class="w3-light-grey">';
          tbl += '<td>' + data[i].QueryTable + '</td>';
          tbl += '<td>' + data[i].JourneyNumber + '</td>';
          tbl += '<td>' + data[i].DeclarationNumber + '</td>';
          tbl += '<td>' + data[i].RMSChannel + '</td>';
          tbl += '<td>' + data[i].CCPID + '</td>';
          tbl += '</tr>';
        }
        tbl += '</table>';
        $tbl.html(tbl);
      },
    })
  }
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />


<div>

  <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" action="">

    <div>
      <table border="1" id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered "></table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try $('#tbl').DataTable({ in #ajax success after  $tbl.html(tbl);

Comment: You have a mismatch in the number of headers and number of columns.  This is the reason. And please stop reinventing the wheel and overcomplicate simple tasks, you have ajax to do the above -> https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html